# Drupal7 programmatically log user in with username only

Tags: authentication, drupal

I'd like to log in by passing a url like "http://example.com?name=admin"
(which I will encryption after)
If a user is exsist, login directly, if not, direct to /user page

I look up some solutions, but almost all of them need to provide password to authentication.

There is an api : user_login_finalize()
but have no idea how to use it

Can anyone help me out how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

```
$name = urldecode($_GET["name"]);

$sso = user_load_by_name($name);
if(!$sso){
// User doesn't exist
echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
} 
else {
// User exists
echo 'Welcome!'.$name;
}
```

Comment: Looks like security hole to me. How (what) are you gonna encrypt later?

Answer (score 1):

Usually it goes like this:

```
$uid = user_authenticate($username, $password);
$account = array('uid' => $uid);
user_login_submit(array(), $account);
```

But in your case, since you don't have password, should be (I didn't try it) like:

```
$user = user_load_by_name($usernamename);
$account = array('uid' => $user->uid);
user_login_submit(array(), $account);
```

Also check these pages:

https://www.drupal.org/project/login_activity/issues/2066899

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.module/function/user_load_by_name/7.x

And be careful not to make security hole to your site.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 1):

Its as simple as:

`global $user;
$user = $sso;
user_login_finalize($user->uid);`

in your else block.

However, its better to rethink about security issues of such a scenario...

Comment: Thank you!! Users are logged in from another site. And I will encrypt the login link to drupal. Thanks for your reminding!

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
define('DRUPAL_ROOT', getcwd());
require_once DRUPAL_ROOT . '/includes/bootstrap.inc';
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);

$sso = urldecode($_GET["name"]);
$user = user_load_by_name($sso);

if(!$user){
    drupal_goto('user/login');
} 
else {
    $user_id = $user->uid;
    user_login_finalize($user_id);
    drupal_goto('<front>');
}
```